# Link to Excel from Word: This object is corrupt or no longer available

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink

I have a Word 2010 document, with linked objects to pivot tables in a Excel 2012 document.
Every night, a macro runs to update the underlying data for the pivot tables in Excel, and refresh these tables.

Next, a macro in Word update all the Excel links in Word, to pick up the changes in the pivot tables.

At some point, the links in Word because corrupt.  When right-click on the table in Word, there is no "Update Link" option.  It is replaced by a menu item called "object", and when I click on that, error pop up is "This object is corrupt or no longer available".

I tried refreshing the links by going to File -> "Edit Links to Files, then "Change Source..." and re-select the Excel file again.  After this refresh, I can do "Update Link".  But If i save and close the file, the link becomes corrupt again.

Not sure if this is somehow related, but when I first manually update the link in word, the link type is "Worksheet".  When I save & reopen, the link type becomes "Excel.Sheet.12".

Any ideas on how to stop the links from becoming corrupt on closing/re-opening the file?

Comment: I'm having the same issue -- any luck on fixing this? When I close/reopen all links break and I get the "Error! Not a valid Link" when I try and update.

Comment: Never figured it out. Rolled back to an older word doc where there was no corruption and it magically started working again.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of *right click* `->` *update field*, select your objects and press <kbd>F9</kbd>. Or, if you want to update the entire document, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>F9</kbd>.