# when updating linked objects,Microsoft Word body text has been hidden

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

When I closed my Microsoft Word document and reopened it, I saw when right-click on the tables in Word which had been linked to a Excel file, there is no “update link” option and it is replaced by a menu item called "object", and when I click on that, an error pop up saying "This object is corrupt or no longer available". This problem has been discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/488895/link-to-excel-from-word-this-object-is-corrupt-or-no-longer-available). I followed the answer, pressing CTRL+A +F9 simultaneously. After doing that, all the Word main text has been hidden and just footnotes and endnotes a
are visible. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Field code off by CTRL+A+F9.