# Problems with links form word to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, links

I am used to link excel tables and cells in to word using paste special/past link/HTML format (unformatted text). Sometimes I encounter with two problems that maybe are related to each other (but I am not sure about it).

First problem: sometime, after linking excel tables (cells), the pointer goes to a state in which it get constantly moving in a little blue circle. In this situation, everything in Word is extremely slow and it is impossible to work with. (When I close and open the Word again, this problem is solved.

Second problem: sometime, when opening Word file, for an unknown reason, I am no longer able to update Excel links (through right click or pressing F9) and the “update” option is unavailable and “object” option appears instead (see the attachment). When I click "Object”, I get the error message: “this object is corrupt or is no longer available”. (I have not changed the excel file name or path directory and this problem is not related to openness of excel file and I have tried repairing office but it did not help. I use Word 2016 and Excel 2016).

Any help would be appreciated.

I have also posted this question on [MSO office Word forum](https://ttps://www.msofficeforums.com/word/49907-problems-links-form-excel-word.html). (https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/49907-problems-links-form-excel-word.html.)

[image]

Comment: The blue circle is most likely from clicking your mouse wheel by accident. Just click the wheel once again, and the scroll mode will toggle off.

Comment: The second issues is a bit more tricky. My first suggestion would have been to make sure the excel file is open before trying to refresh. Otherwise, if the file path hasn't changed, what about the sheet name or cell ref? Did you cut and move any cells in the source? Lastly it might be a language issue. Change windows/office language to English US and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: @ExcelEverything .Thank you for your comments.
For the first issue, I don’t think your comments holds because it is clearly caused by Excel links and if I unlink such links (through ctr+shift+f9) the issue is solved

Comment: For the second issue, it is likely that I have cut some Excel cells which are linked to Word file (for example A1:b3) and pasted them to another place (for example c1:d3). However, as far as I know and as my experiences shows, in such situation Excel links remain intact. (In the above Example Word link refer to new value in A1:b3) in addition when second issue arise it affect all the Excel links not just links related to cells which has been cut. The language of my windows is English Us and I have not changed the name of Excel sheets

Comment: Ah, a misunderstood what you meant with the blue circle. That is the "busy" icon, and is possibly caused by Windows struggling to locate the data. Are all the data on the same local drive? Any network drives, shared folders, or other active programs or users that might be "locking" access to that location?

Comment: Yes. they are in the same local drive. No.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be related:

[Link to Excel from Word: This object is corrupt or no longer available](https://superuser.com/questions/488895/link-to-excel-from-word-this-object-is-corrupt-or-no-longer-available)

Suggestions:

1. Do not update with right-click "update", but rather CTRL+A to select all, then press F9 to update all
2. Update the source file links: File > Info > Edit Links to Files > Change Source...
3. The Word file may be corrupted in some way. Does the problem still occur in a new document with links? If so, revert to an older version, or otherwise try to "reset" the document, try:

   ```
   3.1 Deleting all objects, delete all links via File > Info > ... menu.
   3.2 Save as an old version of Word .doc, then resave as .docx.
   3.3 Copy and paste all the text into a new document. Reformat and re-insert new links.
   ```

Comment: For the answer, the first and second solution do not work and the problem is not related to third solution. I think the problem may be related to Excel file, which is itself, has been linked to an external file. (Although I am not sure about it. This does not mean, if I break excel links, the Word links will be recovered but it means if I avoid from linking a Excel which is to be linked from Word file, the Word links can be saved.)